# How to make timer in alpine.js app with time interval

Tags: alpine.js

With alpine.js 2 I try to make timer with definition in footer (which is set for all layout) of the app :

```
<div>
    
    <div  x-data="appFooterComponent()" x-init=" console.log('initTimer()::'); refreshTime();
    setInterval(refreshTime, 1000) ; console.log('END initTimer::');">
        <div >
            ...
            <span style="background-color: yellow" x-text="refreshTime(@this)"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // THAT DOES NOT WORK
    // this.refreshTime()
    // setInterval(refreshTime, 1000)

    function appFooterComponent() {
        return {
            refreshTime() {
                return moment(new Date()).format('DD MMMM, YYYY HH:mm:ss')
            },
        }
    } 

</script>
```

As result when any new page is opened I see how current datetime is set, but without interval and time is not refreshed any second.
In console I see output of  x-init console commands, but not time interval...
How to fix it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Would the following work?

What you probably want to do with Alpine.js is have a `time` variable that you update (using setInterval), then you can read the formatted time using `this.time` and the relevant Moment.js expression.

```html
<div>
    <div x-data="appFooterComponent()" x-init="init()">
        <div>
            ...
            <span style="background-color: yellow" x-text="getTime()"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function appFooterComponent() {
        return {
            time: new Date(),
            init() {
              setInterval(() => {
                this.time = new Date();
              }, 1000);
            },
            getTime() {
                return moment(this.time).format('DD MMMM, YYYY HH:mm:ss')
            },
        }
    } 

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it work, but do we really need time var ?

Comment: Yeah you need to store _something_ so that Alpine.js knows to re-render. That "something" could be the `formattedTime` if you prefer

Comment: Great example. Where did you find the alpinjs documentation for that?

Comment: I've contributed to the project quite a bit so I guess there's no docs for this specifically. You'll note that  most of the interesting stuff is "just JS".