# AlpineJS: How to pass a x-for variable to an x-data function

Tags: alpine.js

could you please help?

I 'm trying to add a count down according to some property in a loop but I could not find any way (not by trying out nor by googling) how I could pass that value in my functions:

```
    <template x-for="item in cartData.items">
       [...]
        <template x-if="item.product_type == 'test'">
            <div  x-data="getCountdown()" x-init="init()">
                <span x-text="timeLeft(item.timerEnd)"></span>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">[...]
            </script>
        </template>
    </template>
```

I was trying to pass item.timerEnd to every functon (`getCountdown`, `init` and `timeLeft`) but  I always get the error that `item` is undefined, wheras if I pass it eg. to
`<span x-text="new Date(item.timerEnd).toLocaleString()"></span>` this works.

What am I missing?

PS: Thanks fpr the first help here: [How to make timer in alpine.js app with time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471378/how-to-make-timer-in-alpine-js-app-with-time-interval)

Comment: The `x-for` must have one root element only, as per [this doc](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/for).

Answer (score 0):

Do this `$data.item.timerEnd`.

Like this:

```
<template x-for="item in cartData.items">
       [...]
        <template x-if="item.product_type == 'test'">
            <div  x-data="getCountdown($data.item.timerEnd)" x-init="init($data.item.timerEnd)">
                <span x-text="timeLeft($data.item.timerEnd)"></span>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">[...]
            </script>
        </template>
    </template>
```